# ListView MouseClick event error C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have some code, which put URL into ListView. After lmb click I have error:

```
"The system cannot find the file specified".
```

What's wrong?
Code:

```
private void listView2_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
         try
         {
             string[] link = new string[] { listView2.SelectedItems[columnHeader1.Index].Text};  
             Process.Start(link.ToString().Trim()); 
         }
         catch (Win32Exception ex)
         {
             MessageBox.Show("An error has occured: " + ex.Message);
         }
    }
```

Comment: Link indicates a WebLink or local path.  Can you clarify it?

Comment: What is the value of `link.ToString()`? Have you debugged your program?

Comment: It's a weblink of forum

Comment: Value - weblink without \r\n after Trim(). Then, I write link.ToString(). Sure, debugged. It's step to catch block

Comment: Indexing with columnHeader1.Index does not make sense, it starts at 0.  SelectedItems can have more than 1 element if the ListView.MultiSelect property is True.  Just iterate with foreach.

Answer (score 0):

This is a machine-specific problem, depending on your default browser, it may or may not work.

You may need to check for the default browser set and use it to launch the URL.

I believe this article will help:

http://www.seirer.net/blog/2014/6/10/solved-how-to-open-a-url-in-the-default-browser-in-csharp